# Building libcbor, but objects do not reflect in ELF

Tags: c, eclipse, arm, elf, nm

I have an ELF compiled from the sources having following `file`, `size` output:

```
bash.exe"-3.1$ file FreeRTOS_Trial_CubeMX_Project.elf
FreeRTOS_Trial_CubeMX_Project.elf: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, EABI5     version
 1 (SYSV), statically linked, not stripped

bash.exe"-3.1$ arm-unknown-nto-qnx6.5.0eabi-size     FreeRTOS_Trial_CubeMX_Project.elf
   text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
   7936      24    4968   12928    3280 FreeRTOS_Trial_CubeMX_Project.elf
```

I have copied an external libcbor source files into the source tree without changing any setting in the Eclipse IDE. On doing an `nm` on it, I do not get the symbols within libcbor source tree:

```
bash.exe"-3.1$ arm-unknown-nto-qnx6.5.0eabi-nm FreeRTOS_Trial_CubeMX_Project.el
f
08001e20 W ADC1_2_IRQHandler
08001e20 W ADC3_IRQHandler
08001edc R AHBPrescTable
08001eec R APBPrescTable
f1e0f85f a BootRAM
08001e20 W BusFault_Handler
08001e20 W CAN1_RX0_IRQHandler
08001e20 W CAN1_RX1_IRQHandler
08001e20 W CAN1_SCE_IRQHandler
08001e20 W CAN1_TX_IRQHandler
08001e20 W COMP_IRQHandler
08001dd8 t CopyDataInit
08001e20 W DFSDM1_FLT0_IRQHandler
08001e20 W DFSDM1_FLT1_IRQHandler
08001e20 W DFSDM1_FLT2_IRQHandler
08001e20 W DFSDM1_FLT3_IRQHandler
08001e20 W DMA1_Channel1_IRQHandler
08001e20 W DMA1_Channel2_IRQHandler
08001e20 W DMA1_Channel3_IRQHandler
08001e20 W DMA1_Channel4_IRQHandler
08001e20 W DMA1_Channel5_IRQHandler
08001e20 W DMA1_Channel6_IRQHandler
08001e20 W DMA1_Channel7_IRQHandler
08001e20 W DMA2_Channel1_IRQHandler
08001e20 W DMA2_Channel2_IRQHandler
08001e20 W DMA2_Channel3_IRQHandler
08001e20 W DMA2_Channel4_IRQHandler
08001e20 W DMA2_Channel5_IRQHandler
08001e20 W DMA2_Channel6_IRQHandler
08001e20 W DMA2_Channel7_IRQHandler
08001e20 W DebugMon_Handler
08001e20 T Default_Handler
08001e20 W EXTI0_IRQHandler
08001e20 W EXTI15_10_IRQHandler
08001e20 W EXTI1_IRQHandler
08001e20 W EXTI2_IRQHandler
08001e20 W EXTI3_IRQHandler
08001e20 W EXTI4_IRQHandler
08001e20 W EXTI9_5_IRQHandler
08001e20 W FLASH_IRQHandler
08001e20 W FMC_IRQHandler
08001e20 W FPU_IRQHandler
08001dee t FillZerobss
08000314 T HAL_GPIO_Init
080004d0 T HAL_GPIO_WritePin
08000220 W HAL_GetTick
08000210 W HAL_IncTick
080001ec T HAL_Init
08001d00 T HAL_InitTick
08001c74 T HAL_MspInit
080002b8 T HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ
08000250 T HAL_NVIC_SetPriority
0800022c T HAL_NVIC_SetPriorityGrouping
080004ec T HAL_PWREx_ControlVoltageScaling
080004dc T HAL_PWREx_GetVoltageRange
08000ba4 T HAL_RCC_ClockConfig
08000d50 T HAL_RCC_GetClockConfig
08000d14 T HAL_RCC_GetHCLKFreq
08000d20 T HAL_RCC_GetPCLK2Freq
080005dc T HAL_RCC_GetSysClockFreq
08000718 T HAL_RCC_OscConfig
080002fc T HAL_SYSTICK_CLKSourceConfig
080002d0 T HAL_SYSTICK_Config
08000fea W HAL_TIMEx_BreakCallback
08000fe8 W HAL_TIMEx_CommutationCallback
08000fb4 T HAL_TIM_Base_Init
08000d8c W HAL_TIM_Base_MspInit
08000d8e T HAL_TIM_Base_Start_IT
08000da6 W HAL_TIM_IC_CaptureCallback
08000dac T HAL_TIM_IRQHandler
08000da4 W HAL_TIM_OC_DelayElapsedCallback
08000da8 W HAL_TIM_PWM_PulseFinishedCallback
08001c60 T HAL_TIM_PeriodElapsedCallback
08000daa W HAL_TIM_TriggerCallback
08001e20 W HardFault_Handler
08001e20 W I2C1_ER_IRQHandler
08001e20 W I2C1_EV_IRQHandler
08001e20 W I2C2_ER_IRQHandler
08001e20 W I2C2_EV_IRQHandler
08001e20 W I2C3_ER_IRQHandler
08001e20 W I2C3_EV_IRQHandler
08001e20 t Infinite_Loop
08001e20 W LCD_IRQHandler
08001e20 W LPTIM1_IRQHandler
08001e20 W LPTIM2_IRQHandler
08001e20 W LPUART1_IRQHandler
08001de0 t LoopCopyDataInit
08001df4 t LoopFillZerobss
08001e06 t LoopForever
08001eac R MSIRangeTable
08001e20 W MemManage_Handler
08001e20 W NMI_Handler
08001e20 W OTG_FS_IRQHandler
08001e20 W PVD_PVM_IRQHandler
08001790 T PendSV_Handler
08001e20 W QUADSPI_IRQHandler
08001e20 W RCC_IRQHandler
08000558 t RCC_SetFlashLatencyFromMSIRange
08001e20 W RNG_IRQHandler
08001e20 W RTC_Alarm_IRQHandler
08001e20 W RTC_WKUP_IRQHandler
08001dd0 W Reset_Handler
08001e20 W SAI1_IRQHandler
08001e20 W SAI2_IRQHandler
08001e20 W SDMMC1_IRQHandler
08001e20 W SPI1_IRQHandler
08001e20 W SPI2_IRQHandler
08001e20 W SPI3_IRQHandler
08001700 T SVC_Handler
08001e20 W SWPMI1_IRQHandler
08001afc T StartDefaultTask
08001d78 T SysTick_Handler
08001b06 T SystemClock_Config
20000004 D SystemCoreClock
08001d88 T SystemInit
08001e20 W TAMP_STAMP_IRQHandler
08001e20 W TIM1_BRK_TIM15_IRQHandler
08001e20 W TIM1_CC_IRQHandler
08001e20 W TIM1_TRG_COM_TIM17_IRQHandler
08001d7c T TIM1_UP_TIM16_IRQHandler
08001e20 W TIM2_IRQHandler
08001e20 W TIM3_IRQHandler
08001e20 W TIM4_IRQHandler
08001e20 W TIM5_IRQHandler
08001e20 W TIM6_DAC_IRQHandler
08001e20 W TIM7_IRQHandler
08001e20 W TIM8_BRK_IRQHandler
08001e20 W TIM8_CC_IRQHandler
08001e20 W TIM8_TRG_COM_IRQHandler
08001e20 W TIM8_UP_IRQHandler
08000ef0 T TIM_Base_SetConfig
08001e20 W TSC_IRQHandler
08001e20 W UART4_IRQHandler
08001e20 W UART5_IRQHandler
08001e20 W USART1_IRQHandler
08001e20 W USART2_IRQHandler
08001e20 W USART3_IRQHandler
08001e20 W UsageFault_Handler
08001e20 W WWDG_IRQHandler
         w _Jv_RegisterClasses
00000200 A _Min_Heap_Size
00000400 A _Min_Stack_Size
08001e80 t __EH_FRAME_BEGIN__
20000d6c b __bss_end__
20000008 b __bss_start__
         U __call_exitprocs
         w __deregister_frame_info
08000190 t __do_global_dtors_aux
08001f10 t __do_global_dtors_aux_fini_array_entry
08001f08 ? __exidx_end
08001f08 ? __exidx_start
08001f08 t __frame_dummy_init_array_entry
08001f0c t __init_array_end
08001f08 t __init_array_start
         U __libc_fini_array
08001e24 T __libc_init_array
08001f08 d __preinit_array_end
08001f08 d __preinit_array_start
         w __register_frame_info
         U __stack
20000d6c B _ebss
20000008 D _edata
20018000 A _estack
08001e98 T _etext
08001e8c T _fini
08001e80 T _init
         U _printf_float
20000008 B _sbss
20000000 D _sdata
08001f18 A _sidata
         U atexit
20000008 b completed.8605
20000d2c B defaultTaskHandle
20000d70 b end
080001b4 t frame_dummy
08000000 R g_pfnVectors
         U hardware_init_hook
20000d30 B htim1
08001b84 T main
08001e70 T memset
2000000c b object.8610
08001026 T osDelay
08000fec T osKernelStart
08001036 T osSystickHandler
08000ff6 T osThreadCreate
080010f0 t prvAddCurrentTaskToDelayedList
08001578 t prvIdleTask
0800192c t prvInsertBlockIntoFreeList
0800169c t prvPortStartFirstTask
080010d0 t prvResetNextTaskUnblockTime
0800166c t prvTaskExitError
08001970 T pvPortMalloc
20000030 B pxCurrentTCB
080017f0 t pxCurrentTCBConst
08001720 t pxCurrentTCBConst2
20000024 b pxDelayedTaskList
20000160 b pxEnd
2000004c b pxOverflowDelayedTaskList
080016d0 T pxPortInitialiseStack
20000068 b pxReadyTasksLists
         U software_init_hook
20000164 b ucHeap
20000150 b ucMaxSysCallPriority
20000154 b ulMaxPRIGROUPValue
20000d28 B uwTick
20000000 d uxCriticalNesting
20000064 b uxCurrentNumberOfTasks
20000138 b uxDeletedTasksWaitingCleanUp
080010ae T uxListRemove
20000148 b uxPendedTicks
2000013c b uxSchedulerSuspended
20000134 b uxTaskNumber
20000034 b uxTopReadyPriority
0800104a T vListInitialise
08001060 T vListInitialiseItem
0800107e T vListInsert
08001066 T vListInsertEnd
080016bc t vPortEnableVFP
08001724 T vPortEnterCritical
08001768 T vPortExitCritical
08001a8c T vPortFree
08001820 W vPortSetupTimerInterrupt
0800152c T vTaskDelay
080012e8 T vTaskStartScheduler
08001354 T vTaskSuspendAll
080015e8 T vTaskSwitchContext
20000d24 b xBlockAllocatedBit
200000f4 b xDelayedTaskList1
20000108 b xDelayedTaskList2
20000d20 b xFreeBytesRemaining
20000140 b xIdleTaskHandle
20000d1c b xMinimumEverFreeBytesRemaining
20000028 b xNextTaskUnblockTime
20000144 b xNumOfOverflows
20000050 b xPendingReadyList
08001848 T xPortStartScheduler
080017f4 T xPortSysTickHandler
20000130 b xSchedulerRunning
20000158 b xStart
20000038 b xSuspendedTaskList
08001160 T xTaskCreate
0800164c T xTaskGetSchedulerState
08001368 T xTaskIncrementTick
08001454 T xTaskResumeAll
2000011c b xTasksWaitingTermination
2000002c b xTickCount
2000014c b xYieldPending
```

however it generates the output.map file with the libcbor symbols. See [this](http://pasted.co/c5f631c1). Search for "libcbor" in the link. Another link if that one doesn't work: https://justpaste.it/14i4h

Why would this happen? Am I failing to understand something here or missed something during my build?

Any help is appreciated very much. Thanks.

Comment: your link doesn't work for me. Can you show the relevant parts of the mapfile in the question please?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre, try this link instead: https://justpaste.it/14i4h search for "libcbor" in it

Comment: sorry, no go either.

Comment: Seems I can't paste the relevant sections of the map file, the size is more than 30000 characters and StackOverflow is not accepting it.

Comment: try this: https://paste.ee/p/3OxJA

Comment: my firewall is good you know :) you could paste a small extract of your relevant portion, it would be something at least.